# Converting exact margin requirements to areaset command

Tags: margins, koma-script

How do I find out what `\areaset` command to use for a specific margin requirement, e.g., `left=2.5cm`, `right=2.5cm`, `top=2.5cm` and `bottom=3cm`?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example for people to work with.

Comment: If you have a specific margin requirement, why not use `geometry`?

Comment: It's because I'm using classicthesis and when I specify the margins with the geometry package, it does not affect the chapter numbers, that get messed up.  Some disappear, some show outside the margin.  So this is really about margins for classicthesis, when the geometry solution is not applicable.  It seems I can approximate it with \areaset experiments though.

Comment: Classicthesis explains the reasoning for the margin setting and says it should not be altered. `classicthesis` is not suited for university theses. Fin.

Comment: @user1603472 There is no MWE in your question ... Using `geometry` you can set `marginparsep=12pt, marginparwidth=47pt` additionally. These are the values which `\areaset` would use (see the example in my answer). But note that your right margin is to small for `classicthesis`  chapter numbers larger than 9.

Answer (score 9):

Command `\areaset` from package `typearea` (KOMA-Script bundle) sets the dimensions of the text body, i.e. the width and the height of the text area and as optional argument a binding offset (`BCOR`).

As a result of the layout calculation by `typearea` the foot margin will be be nearly twice as high as the top margin. So it is not possible to get your desired margins by using `\areaset`.

From scrguien.pdf (KOMA-Script documentation):

> The `typearea` package was not made to set up predefined margin values. If you have to do so you may use package `geometry`

So the recommended way to set required margins is using package `geometry` even if a KOMA-Script class is used.

---

**Update**

Example with `\areaset` and a onesided document:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\areaset
  {\dimexpr\the\paperwidth-5cm\relax}% calculate requiered \textwidth
  {\dimexpr\the\paperheight-5.5cm\relax}% calculate requiered \textheight

\usepackage{layout}
\begin{document}
\layout
\end{document}
```

[image]

So the resulting text height is `688 pt`, but the top and the bottom margins are `51pt=1.8cm` and `106pt=3.7cm`, respectively.

If you use `geometry`

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{layout}
\begin{document}
\layout
\end{document}
```

you get

[image]

So with `geometry` the text height is also `688pt`, but the top and the bottom margins have the required dimensions: `71pt=2.5cm` and `86pt=3cm`.

Note that if there is a `twoside` document and you use `\areaset` the outer margin will twice as wide the inner margin.

Comment: Well if you can define the text area you should also be able to define the margin, shouldn't you?  The margin would be the paper size minus the text area?  What I'm looking for is an algorithm to work out the text area that best approximates my requirements.

Comment: Of course you can calculate a text height by paper height minus 5.5 cm. But `\areaset` will not split the 5.5cm in 2.5 cm top margin and 3 cm bottom margin. As I have already said the bottom margin would be twice as high as the top margin.

Comment: "the outer margin will be twice as wide as the inner margin" I understand that it's orthodox for a books inner margins, but I have bad memories of struggling with books, trying to open them flat enough to read the text near the inner margin.  I guess they just didn't have the [BCOR] set correctly, though.